# How to upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi ISO

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, grub2, wubi

I have downloaded, Ubuntu 12.04 ISO Wubi installer ISO I believe. I have Ubuntu 11.10. I want to know how to upgrade 11.10 with this Wubi Ubuntu 12.04 ISO. Since I got Grub, I don't want to have both Linux. Is it possible I make Wubi ISO of 12.04 upgrade from 11.10 using grub way or on Ubuntu 11.10 logged in

Comment: Can`t you run the upgrade online?

Comment: I needed the Wubi for future as well, Actually , I upgraded from Maverick version. So I need this 12.04 version on USB as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use Zsync.
The above link provides an opportunity to zsync the existing iso with the required ISO[Provides the working images](http://klikit.pbworks.com/w/page/7315137/Updating%20with%20Zsync)

[This provides the details of Zsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zsync)